# Mysql Query modify

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my Query I want to get latest record in each group.I have two table `t_service_request` and `t_request_chkpoint`

```
t_service_request
------------
LTS,JFT,CUS_NO,REQUETST_ID...                

t_request_chkpoint 
------------
LTS ,REQUETST_ID...
```

Both table match by `REQUETST_ID`.

I want to group by `cus_no` in table `t_service_request`

```
SELECT S.*, A.ID as CID, A.ENTRY_ID, A.LTS
FROM maintenance.t_service_request S 
WHERE JFT IN (
    SELECT MAX(JFT)
    FROM maintenance.t_service_request
    GROUP BY CUS_NO
) LEFT OUTER JOIN maintenance.t_request_chkpoint A 
ON S.REQUEST_ID = A.REQUEST_ID where S.COMPANY_ID = '0002' AND S.STATE >= 3 AND A.STATE >= 3
```

but didn't work any suggestions ?

```
t_service_request
------------         
LTS|JFT|CUS_NO|REQUETST_ID|

t_request_chkpoint
------------         
|LTS|REQUETST_ID|
```

Join above two table(`Request_id`) and select latest `JFT` in each `CUS_NO`

Comment: What does "but didn't work" mean? A syntax error? Too many rows? Too few? Something else?

Comment: This works select a.lts,max(a.jft),a.cus_no,a.request_id,b.lts,b.request_id from t_service_request a join t_service_chkpoint b on a.request_id = b.request_id group by a.cus_no;

but duplicates records select

Comment: What's kind of your duplicates records? Actually you can provide more information of your table, like structure, sample data etc.

Comment: in JFT 20160302144400, 20160327113100, 20160315134500, 20160313164200, 20160323103000,

Comment: I still don't understand what is working, what is not, and what  "but didn't work" is supposed to mean. I have posted an answer, though. I think this will get us quicker to where we want to get.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, maybe works;)

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  S.*,
  A.ID AS CID,
  A.ENTRY_ID,
  A.LTS
FROM maintenance.t_service_request S
LEFT JOIN maintenance.t_request_chkpoint A ON A.REQUETST_ID = S.REQUETST_ID AND A.STATE >= 3
WHERE S.JFT = (SELECT MAX(B.JFT)
               FROM maintenance.t_service_request B
               WHERE B.CUS_NO = S.CUS_NO
               GROUP BY B.CUS_NO)
AND S.COMPANY_ID = '0002' AND S.STATE >= 3
```

I think your sql may have some syntax errors and I am not sure I've misunderstood your requirement or not.

Comment: @Nalincooray I've update my post, plz check it again.

Comment: SELECT S.*, A.ID as CID, A.ENTRY_ID, A.LTS FROM maintenance.t_service_request S LEFT JOIN maintenance.t_request_chkpoint A ON A.REQUEST_ID = S.REQUEST_ID AND S.STATE >= 3 WHERE S.JFT = (SELECT MAX(B.JFT) FROM maintenance.t_service_request B WHERE B.CUS_NO = S.CUS_NO GROUP BY B.CUS_NO)AND S.COMPANY_ID = '0002' AND S.STATE >= 3 AND A.STATE >= 3  this is work but select duplicate records

Comment: @Nalincooray hmm, add a `DISTINCT` keyword in sql.

Comment: where i add DISTINCT in my query

Comment: @Nalincooray I've modified my sql, check it again.

Comment: I added DISTINCT as you said but same results

Comment: @Nalincooray Could you provide some sample data in your post? Cause I don't know what actual data it is.

Comment: in JFT
 20160302144400,
20160327113100,
20160315134500,
20160313164200,
20160323103000,

Answer (score 0):

I must admit, I still don't understand what you are asking. Your query, however, is incomplete, and maybe fixing it solves your problem already.

You say you want "to get latest record in each group" and in your query you are looking for the maximum `JFT` per `CUS_NO`. Then, however you are only comparing the `JFT` and not the `CUS_NO`.

Moreover, your query is syntactically incorrect, as it has two WHERE clauses. Last but not least, (outer) join criteria (`state >= 3` here) belongs in the ON clause, not in the WHERE clause.

Here is the corrected query:

```
select
  sr.*, 
  rc.id as cid, 
  rc.entry_id, 
  rc.lts
from maintenance.t_service_request sr 
left outer join maintenance.t_request_chkpoint rc on rc.request_id = sr.request_id
                                                  and rc.state >= 3
where sr.company_id = '0002' and sr.state >= 3
and (sr.cus_no, sr.jft) in 
(
  select cus_no, max(jft)
  from maintenance.t_service_request
  group by cus_no
);
```

Comment: Thank you it worked ....if i want to select latest 2 or 3 record how can do that?

Comment: That would be more complicated. Rather than selecting `MAX(jft)` in the subquery, you'd have to select records for which exist no more than one or two records with a higher jft for the cus_no. That means you'd need a subquery in the subquery. Try it and if you fail come back for help by asking this in a separate SO request.